# Troubles with threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory

Morning everyone,

I was trying to create a very simple application with a single thread , which would simply change a value of an object's variable and then print it on screen. So now whenever I run the program the thread is initialized correctly however it's returning some garbage values for `object->a`.

Could you please give me some pointers as to how I could get this working?

Thanks alot.
Alex

```
HANDLE hPrintMutex;
int ThreadNr;

class object
{
    public:
        int a;
        object(void);
};

object::object(void)
{
    a=1;
}


void printNumber(void * arg)
{
    object * x=(object*) arg;
    std::cout<<"Thread1 -> "<< x->a<<"\n";;
    while(x->a<10)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hPrintMutex,INFINITE);
        x->a=5;
        ReleaseMutex(hPrintMutex);
    }
}

int main()
{
    object * Object; 
    Object = new object;

    hPrintMutex=CreateMutex(NULL,false,NULL);
    std::cout << "Main -> "<<Object->a<<"\n";

    HANDLE hThread1=(HANDLE)_beginthread(printNumber,0,&Object);

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread1,INFINITE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are not using std::thread, std::mutex or even std::atomic?

Comment: No reason, I just couldn't find any better example for studying the c++ threads. All the other examples seemed very hard to understand.

Comment: @Wracker I believe this is windows api, so they cannot be rightfully called C++ threads. Take a look at [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread), this is the new and "correct" way to do threads now

Comment: Why do you use `object(void)` notation? In contract to C, you do not need this in C++.

Comment: @Karthik T , you're right. Thanks for all the helpful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `object **` to the thread, but treating it as an `object *`

You don't need the `&` in

```
HANDLE hThread1=(HANDLE)_beginthread(printNumber,0,&Object);
                                                   ^
```

Comment: @Wracker you are welcome! Btw, since you are learning, I must say, your naming style is kinda confusing. Typically class names are in caps, i.e `Object`, and variable names are not, i.e `object`.